# Pull Data from 3 mySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that selects all the data from one table and specific columns from another where two columns are equal and another column equals a specific value.

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.column1, table2.column2 FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column3=table2.column3 
WHERE table1.column1='foo';
```

Is it possible to pull `table3.column1` & `table3.column2` from a `table3` where `table3.column3=table1.column3` AND `table3.column4='bar'` ?

The thing that makes it more complex is that the data in table3 is optional and may not always exist; however I still want the query to return table1 & table2's data but with `table3.column1` & `table3.column2` just being presented as NULL or EMPTY...

Im struggling to get my head around it myself, and any insight or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need a LEFT JOIN on the third table, and specify multiple conditions in the ON clause with a boolean AND operator

Comment: You are a literal godsend @Code4R7 | Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.column1, table2.column2, table3.column1, table3.column2
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.column3 = table2.column3 
LEFT JOIN table3
    ON table3.column3 = table1.column3 AND table3.column4 = 'bar'
WHERE table1.column1 = 'foo';
```

When there is no corresponding record in `table3` table3.column1 and table3.column2 will be null

And if column1 and column2 names are not unique column names in select clause you need to give them an alias

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3
from table1 as t1
inner join table2 as t2 on t2.col3.t1.col2
left join table3 as t3 on t3.col3.t2.col2
where t1.col1 = 'test';
```

it can be done like this.